# Return the displayName of an LDAP manager

Tags: vba, active-directory, ldap

I have some code that I use to get the manager of a user - I originally wrote the code for a SharePoint site but was recently asked to write it using VBA.

```
Const SearchField = "DisplayName"
Const ReturnField = "manager"
Public Function MLookup(ByVal SearchString As String) As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strDomain
    strDomain = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE").Get("defaultNamingContext")
    Dim objConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"
    Dim objCommand As ADODB.Command
    Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
    objCommand.CommandText = _
        "<LDAP://" & strDomain & ">;(&(objectCategory=User)" & _
        "(" & SearchField & "=" & SearchString & "));" & SearchField & "," & ReturnField & ";subtree"
    Dim objRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset
    Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
    If objRecordSet.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MLookup = "Not Found"
    Else
        objMngr = objRecordSet.Fields(ReturnField)
        objMngr = Mid(objMngr, 4, InStr(1, objMngr, ",OU"))
        objMngr = Replace(objMngr, "\,", ",")
        objMngr = Left(objMngr, Len(objMngr) - 12)
        MLookup = Trim(objMngr)
    End If
    objConnection.Close
    Set objRecordSet = Nothing
    Set objCommand = Nothing
    Set objConnection = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

This code works fine - runs a little slow because I work from home but it gets the job done. I have run into a snag now though. The manager field returns the user string on the manager however the sting is built using the Distinguised Name - for ladies that means their maiden name. This data is used in a report and has ruffled some feathers because the data appears to them as incorrect. What I want to know is if there is a way to modify the return string of the manager to that person's display name instead of parsing the name out of the manager field? Or is my only solution to create a second function that returns display name (this would double my response time and on 5000 records that might be too much)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple (and only) answer is no. The manager field (and other LDAP object reference fields, such as the multi-value `member` property of `group` objects) contain only the distinguishedName, because that's how objects are identified in LDAP. However, a lookup by distinguishedName should be extremely fast for the same reason.

Without testing I can't be sure, but it may help the speed of your overall process to use the same command and connection objects for all the queries, rather than recreating them for every instance. A way to do that while still maintaining the separation of the method would be to take optional connection and/or command parameters to the method.

Finally, assuming many people will have the same managers, you could cache the display name for each manager using a `Dictionary`, so you only have to look up the display name once for each manager.

Comment: Thanks - that is some great advice. My code currently is written to be used as an equation in a cell of Excel and that could only change if the people who run the report are willing to change.