# Retrieve manager sAMAccountName for each user in AD VBscript

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, adsi

I need to get just the sAMAccountName of the manager not the fully distinguished name!

I am running this and got the distinguished name:

```vb
strUSRDAT_CTAMAN = objRecordSet.Fields("manager").Value
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return the displayName of an LDAP manager](//stackoverflow.com/a/19531338)

Comment: I need the Identity not the displayname

Comment: Still applies, [actually read the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19531338/692942) instead of making assumptions based on the title - *"However, a lookup by distinguishedName should be extremely fast for the same reason."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get attribute values of an AD object via its distinguished name like this:

```
dn  = "cn=foo,ou=bar,dc=dom,dc=example,dc=org"
val = GetObject("LDAP://" & dn).Get("attr_name")
```

In your case

```
manager = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUSRDAT_CTAMAN).Get("sAMAccountName")
```

Comment: @ITMAn Lookup by `distinguishedName` just like [the answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19531338/692942).